# Error type is invalid...error while using "react-switch

Tags: reactjs

I have created a child component for switch using "react-switch" and try to render that child component in parent. But, I got an error like Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Temp`.

```
import * as React from 'react';    
import * as Bs from 'react-bootstrap';    
import Switch from "react-switch";    


interface ITempProps {

}

interface ITempStates {     
    checked: boolean    
}    

export class Temp extends React.Component<ITempProps, ITempStates>{     
    constructor() {    
        super();    
        this.state = { checked: false };    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);     
    }

    handleChange(checked: boolean) {
        this.setState({ checked });
    }

    public render() {
        return <div className="new-main-content">
            <h3>Test Switch</h3>
            <div className="marL20">
                <Bs.Row>
                    <Bs.Col className="text-left" sm={4} componentClass={Bs.ControlLabel}>
                        Toggle-Switch
                    </Bs.Col>
                    <Bs.Col>
                        <Switch 
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            checked={this.state.checked}
                            className="react-switch"
                            id="normal-switch"
                        />
                    </Bs.Col>
                </Bs.Row>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: One of your components is not loading. try running `console.log(Bs, Switch)` in your render before your return statement to check which one is undefined

Comment: Your ITempProps is empty if it's empty, why don't you remove it.

Comment: @ManavM thanks for your quick response. Yes, Switch is coming as an undefined. But Switch is just an imported component from built-in "react-switch" which I got from "npm install react-switch".

Comment: @Mohan Check your node-modules to see if you have react-switch there.

Comment: If it is there then the only other thing I can think of that would cause this is if you have another module or an alias named `react-switch` that is conflicting with the react-switch package